# Google drive api authentication not working on Chrome on iPhone

Tags: iphone, google-chrome, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-client

The following code works great on desktop and laptops, any browser or OS.  It even works fine in Safari on iPhone, but on Google Chrome on iPhone it doesnt.  When my button is pressed a new window opens up that has a blank page that states "Please close the window".  The blank page is pointing to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth` with a bunch of query strings.  Why is Chrome behaving this way on the iPhone?

```
        window.gapi.auth.authorize(
            {
                'client_id': clientId,
                'scope': scope,
                'immediate': false
            },
            handleAuthResult);

   function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        gapi.load('picker', { 'callback': createPicker });
}
```